# Wireless Headphones?

Tags: headphones, wireless, setup

In my VO and ADR room I am considering buying wireless headphones for the talent - this would be awesome to do away with another cable.

Do any of you have experience with a certain type of wireless headphones that you like? All I really need is a reliable setup that sounds good enough for a voice talent (some are less audio-inclined than others, hah!).

I wonder if the RF would interfere with the mics... Any input, anyone?

Your experiences are very much appreciated.

- Ryan

Answer (score 1):

Be carefull with any wireless equipment for monitoring since It always has a limited range of frequences (not all of them can be sent without a wire). Probably it will interfere on your perception of the recorded sound, more or less depending on the wireless transmission technology of the equipment.

Answer (score 0):

The only experience I have with wireless headphones are cheap bluetooth headphones (can't recommend 'em). But Rob Nokes just recommended the [Sennheiser RS-180](http://www.sennheiser.com/sennheiser/home_en.nsf/root/private_headphones_wireless-stereo-headphones_502875?Open&path=private_headphones_hifi_wireless-headphones) wireless headphones today on [Designing Sound](http://designingsound.org/2010/08/rob-nokes-special-reader-questions/).

> **RN:** For studio recording I absolutely love the Sennheiser RS-180 wireless headphones because they are wireless. The sound quality is not “wired” quality but it’s very good considering the price ($300) and the flexibility of working wireless in the studio.

Comment: @Steve I asked that question to him and that's why I asked this question here. Full circle!

Comment: @Ryan That's hilarious. It seemed a little too coincidental!

Answer (score 0):

We use wired but over in Ardmore Sound in Dublin they use wireless in their Foley stage.

Alan (the manager) is a nice chap, he might tell you what they use.

http://www.ardmoresound.com